# Appcelerator Studio (Android) - Run App causes Error: Invalid "--device-id"

Tags: android, titanium, adb, appcelerator

- Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.7.1.201609100950
- Windows 10
- Titanium SDK 4.0.1
- Target SDK 21

If I start AS, the device is found and is registered by adb. When I try to run the app, most of the time (9 of 10 tries) I get an Error:

**[ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "ZX1D229LCD"**

Sometime it works for one run, then the error reoccurred, but the whole time, the adb state is device and it is the correct device id. It happens on all testing devices I have.

I changed workspace, reinstalled Appcelerator Studio, reinstalled Android SDK, cleaned Project, reconnect Device, installed driver, activate MTP ... nothing worked.

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150675/titanium-cli-on-win-7-eperm-operation-not-permitted-c-program-files-gemein

Comment: didn't work for me ... both error's still occure :-(

Comment: here is the issue related to it https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-1496

Comment: I removed the genymotion problem ... the main error is the invalid device id that make it hart to test my app ... I do not know what to do, nothing worked.